# How to load multiple images in ViewPager using Glide?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, picasso, android-glide

first of all I am a beginner in Android development and really hope that you guys can help me out. I want to load 3 images from Firebase into my viewpager which can be slide.

I managed to load 2 images and make it shown on the viewpager, but when I tried to set the third images using Glide and Picasso, the app crashed and it stated that "argument must not be null" when I'm using Glide,  and "target must not be null" when I'm using Picasso. My images sizes is around 60kb each. When i put a tag, it shows that all the pictures already been downloaded from Firebase, but somehow, the third images cannot be shown on the viewpager and make the app crashes.

Below is my ViewPagerAdapter. Thank you very much in advance.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
public static final String TAG_FRAGMENT = "FirebaseImageViewer";
private static final String TAG = "FirebaseImageViewer";
private DatabaseReference bannerReference;
private ImageView[] images = new ImageView[3];

public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, DatabaseReference bannerReference) 
{
    this.context = context;
    this.bannerReference = bannerReference;

    bannerReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String image =(String)dataSnapshot.child("banner1").getValue();
            String image2 =(String)dataSnapshot.child("banner2").getValue();             
            String image3 =(String)dataSnapshot.child("banner3").getValue();



                       Glide.with(ViewPagerAdapter.this.context)
                       .asBitmap()
                       .load("image").into(images[0]); 

                       Glide.with(ViewPagerAdapter.this.context)
                      .asBitmap()
                      .load("image2")
                      .into(images[1]);  

                       Glide.with(ViewPagerAdapter.this.context)
                      .asBitmap()
                      .load("image3")
                      .into(images[2]);

                                         }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

}


@Override
public int getCount() {return images.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {



    images[position] = new ImageView(ViewPagerAdapter.this.context);
    int padding = ViewPagerAdapter.this
            .context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
    images[position].setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

    images[position].setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);


    container.addView(images[position], position);
    return images[position];
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((ImageView) object);


}
```

below is the error log,

```
D/FirebaseImageViewer: image loaded 
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/kahwin2-
6ca62.appspot.com/o/Banner_Contents%2Fkahwinmadeeasy.png?
alt=media&token=df1e45d9-c34b-45a5-b26f-fe4bbfffa7e4

D/FirebaseImageViewer: image loaded 
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/kahwin2-
6ca62.appspot.com/o/Banner_Contents%2Fbanner2.png?alt=media&token=fa9757fa-
e734-4151-bb52-486d499c192d

D/FirebaseImageViewer: image loaded 
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/kahwin2-
6ca62.appspot.com/o/Banner_Contents%2Fbanner3.png?alt=media&token=014ee8c4-
a600-4325-9cc5-87d8535805c9

W/Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from 
android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, 
returning read-only value.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.something.android.kahwinkahwin, PID: 6051
              java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
                  at 
com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:618)
                  at 
com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:601)
                  at com.something.android.kahwinkahwin.ViewPagerAdapter$1.
onDataChange(ViewPagerAdapter.java:52)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.
zzbpx.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZV(Unknown 
Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown 
Source)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.
main(ActivityThread.java:6334)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.
run(ZygoteInit.java:886)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.
main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: check the value of image[2] that's not null

Comment: I'm sorry, how do I check the value? all the images link are correct btw.

Comment: log the images values and check if any one have null

Comment: the third image was stated to be null.

Comment: so how you will load a null image :D

Comment: I mean, why it is null? i tried changing links and it still stated null. What can i do to make it not null?

Comment: ok whre the images array it's value comes from

Comment: the image is downloaded from Firebase which is the "banner1", "banner2", and "banner3", from my log, it stated that all of these images had been downloaded, i will show the log on the above. thank you very much sir for replying my question.

Comment: ok i know the problem i will put the answer

Comment: try the following: call [setOffscreenPageLimit(3)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)). I think that the ImageView is null, not the underlying Bitmap

Comment: Thanks Midas for your suggestion, it works!!! thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem as follow you download the images from firebase and save them in `image` , `image2` and `image3` but when you load the image using glide you pass it the the `banner` string instead of image variable so the correct solution will look like this

```
               Glide.with(ViewPagerAdapter.this.context)
               .asBitmap()
               .load(image).into(images[0]); 

               Glide.with(ViewPagerAdapter.this.context)
              .asBitmap()
              .load(image2)
              .into(images[1]);  

               Glide.with(ViewPagerAdapter.this.context)
              .asBitmap()
              .load(image3)
              .into(images[2]);
```

Comment: I'm sorry Mr. Ahmed, I wrongly typed my code in StackOverflow, I actually wrote like what you wrote on the above. thus, it still stated null.

Comment: ah i read you error the problem is image view not yet draw so it's null and you can't load image into null object i think you should do it in another way

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by using the suggestion from MidasLefko which is to set the setOffScreenPageLimit(3). It is defaulted at 1.